# Сформировать одномерный массив, где и меняется от 0 до m-1

Tags: массивы, c++

Дан вещественный двумерный массив A размера m x n. Сформировать одномерный массив B = [bi] где и меняется от 0 до m-1, где bi это сумма элементов, предшествующих последнему отрицательному элементу i-ой стоки A(если все элементы строки неотрицательны, то принять bi = -1). Никак не пойму её....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А я понял - вот. Анализируете каждую строку А, начиная с конца. Доходите до первого отрицательного элемента и со следующего начинаете составлять сумму (bi), она может оказаться и нулевой. Если она равна нулю, и последний в цикле (первый в строке) элемент > 0, то bi = -1.